# App keep stopping in react native maps and react native firebase

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, react-native-maps

I use `react-native-maps` along with `react-native-firebase` and i face `play-services-base` collide issue. In react native maps dependencies `play-services-base:10.2.4` and `play-services-maps:10.2.4`. React native firebase uses 11.4.2

When run-android my app keep stopping with no error. It is fine when i remove react native maps module.

Here is my gradle

```
compile(project(':react-native-maps')) 
{
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
}    
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2') {    
    force = true;
}
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2') {
    force = true;
}

compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
    transitive = false
}
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2"
```

I am no familiar with gradle and java.

Answer (score 1):

Do you also have other libraries which have dependency with com.google.android.gms or com.google.firebase? you can refer this [post](https://medium.com/@suchydan/how-to-solve-google-play-services-version-collision-in-gradle-dependencies-ef086ae5c75f)

I modified build.gradle as below

```
dependencies {
 compile project(':react-native-config')
 compile project(':react-native-version-number')
 compile(project(':react-native-maps')){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
 }
 compile (project(':react-native-fcm')){
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase'
 }
 compile (project(':react-native-device-info')){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-gcm'
 }
 compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase'
    transitive = false
 }
 .......
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'

 compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
 compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2") {
    force = true;
 }
 compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.2") {
    force = true;
 }
 compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2") {
    force = true;
 }
 compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2") {
    force = true;
 }
 compile ("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2") { //this decides your firebase SDK version
    force = true;
}
 // RNFirebase optional dependencies
 compile ("com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.4.2") {
    force = true;
 }
 compile ("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2") {
    force = true;
 }
 compile ("com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.4.2") {
    force = true;
 }
 compile ("com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.2") {
    force = true;
 }
 compile ("com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2") {
    force = true;
 }
 compile ("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2") {
    force = true;
 }
 compile ("com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.4.2") {
    force = true;
 }
 compile ("com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2") {
    force = true;
 }
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Google play dependencies are an endless pain.